# Operaciones con tiempo

Tags: python

Tengo una base de datos Excel con mensajes AIS, de los cuales se han extraído a un archivo “.csv” varias columnas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los mensajes extraídos han pasado por el filtro de que el campo SOG = 0, es decir, aquellos barcos que están “parados”. La idea de esta usar esta base de datos es hacer uso de algoritmos de clustering para detectar rutas marítimas habituales, para lo que se ha empezado por detectar zonas como fondeaderos o zonas de pesca, asumiendo que la velocidad de los barcos en estas, será nula.
El problema es que, de las columnas de los mensajes AIS, las que tienen una fiabilidad aceptable realmente son solo las coordenadas, por lo que he pensado en hacer un pre-filtrado de los datos algo mejor. Esto es, buscar un código que compare dos posiciones consecutivas y saque la velocidad a la que va el barco en función del tiempo que ha pasado.
He conseguido sacar la distancia en millas náuticas entre dos posiciones con el siguiente código:

```
def distancia_puntos():
    latitudes = X["lat"]
    longitudes = X["lon"]
    lat_1 = radians(latitudes[0])
    lat_2 = radians(latitudes[1])
    lon_1 = radians(longitudes[0])
    lon_2 = radians(longitudes[1])
        
    distancia_rad = acos(sin(lat_1)*sin(lat_2) + cos(lat_1)*cos(lat_2)*cos((lon_1 - lon_2) / cos((lat_1 + lat_2)/2)))
    
    distancia = distancia_rad*180*60/pi
                     
    return distancia

dist = distancia_puntos()
print(dist)
```

Realmente no es complicado, solamente es aplicar una fórmula, mis conocimientos de Python son limitados.
A la hora de enfrentarme a hacer lo propio con el tiempo, estuve toda una tarde intentando restar dos tiempos y sacar la diferencia en horas, y no logré dar con una solución después de probar muchas cosas. Lo que me daba error principalmente solía ser el tema formato.
Por pedir un poco más, y explicar mi caso, la idea que tenía era que el código recorriera las columnas automáticamente, realizando la comparación entre todas las posiciones consecutivas (diferencia de distancia y tiempo de una posición registrada con la siguiente, y así ir sacando las velocidades).
Una parte importante es establecer un umbral aceptable para considerar que un barco está parado, pues es imposible que se mantenga siempre en la misma posición por el abatimiento y la deriva. Por ello, se considerarán parados aquellos barcos cuya velocidad se menor de un nudo (1 nudo = 1 milla náutica / hora).
Además, esto debe realizarlo el mismo barco, por lo que cuando cambiase el valor de la columna “mmsi” no deberíar realizar la comparación (no tendría sentido), continuando con la iteración cuando fuera el mismo.

Comment: Hola, Alvaroliacu. ¿has intentado convertir el string msgtimestamp en un objeto de time (datetime) para restar dos tiempos?